# What user does Lampp run under?

Tags: linux, lampp, htdocs

I was wondering what user Lampp runs under. For instance, if I install apache without lampp it runs under the user apache.

Thank you.

Comment: donno why downvotes it's a very well phrased question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.apachefriends.org/en/faq-xampp-linux.html#sicherer

it says the user name will be lampp

I don't know if that's true in general, but it seems to be true for the pages they have you protecting